# Matching two alternating XPath values into one list

Tags: python, list, selenium, xpath, dataframe

I have encountered this problem:
A page has 5 divs of info, with child values inside of each:
**Title,
Price,
Date.**

Base Lists:

```
Titles = []
Prices = []
Dates = []
```

They all have the same XPath Lead so I can track all of them. Problem is - "Price" sometimes shows and sometimes doesn't in a div.

So what I get is:

```
Titles = [Title1, Title2, Title3, Title4, Title5]
Prices = [Price1, Price2, Price5] #(Missing two non-existing values of 3rd and 4th divs prices)
Dates = [Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4, Date5]
```

Since "Prices" class is not always there inside the div, it catches all of them but unmatching the axis to the correct div belonging. (makes the Price5 align with Title3 and Date3)

So when I do

```
print(len(Titles))
print(len(Prices))
print(len(Dates))
```

Obviously it prints out

```
5
3
5
```

And it cannot be worked with.

The bright side in this case is that every time there is no "Prices" class, a different one shows - "Estimation".

So what I'm trying to do is to find both xpaths of "Prices" and "Estimation" and append them by axis order to the same list, to ultimately get:

```
Titles = [Title1(1), Title2(2), Title3(3), Title4(4), Title5(5)]
Prices = [Price1(1), Price2(2), Estimation1(3), Estimation2(4), Price3(5)]
Dates = [Date1(1), Date2(2), Date3(3), Date4(4), Date5(5)]
```

In () is the (x)axis number to match the correct div.

Then I will have my dataFrame.

**Though I cannot seem to find a way to find them simultaniously and append them by order of appearance.**

Assisstance?

EDIT: Added sample code by request:

```
title = []
price = []
date = []

def grabber():

title_ = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="title-class"]')
for x in title_:
    try:
        title.append(x.text)
    except:
        title.append("N/A")

price_ = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@itemprop="price-class"]')
no_price = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="estimation-class"]')
for x, y in price_, no_price:
    price.append(x.text, "N/A")

# ^ Doesn't work of course ^, One method I tried among many other. 

date_ = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@itemprop="date-class"]')
for x in date_:
    try:
        date.append(x.text)
    except:
        date.append("N/A")
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML?

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying.I added sample code, that works?

Comment: Thanks, see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an [or operation](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp)  via a pipe (`|`), combining your two XPaths into one:

Pseudocode:

```
//div/price | //price
```

---

EDIT from OP's code:

```
price_ = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@itemprop="price-class"]')
no_price = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="estimation-class"]')
```

can be combined into:

```
price_ = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//*[@itemprop="price-class"] | //*[@class="estimation-class"]')
```

Comment: Works BEAUTIFULLY.